# Xcode 10.0 Error "Command /Applications/Xcode 10.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1"

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

When I compile my code on XCode Version 10.0 I get this single error bringing the compilation to failure:

I will try all the possibility but can't solve the error

- Clean My project **alt + Shift + Command + K**
- deleting ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
- Pod Update

Comment: Would you please check some of the class had the same name or not?

Comment: what does it work in Xcode 9.2 or 9.4?

Comment: @FaysalAhmed i checked all code there is no any same class

Comment: @DhavalUmraliya yes It's working proprly in Xcode 9.2 and  9.4

Comment: Even I'm facing the same problem from the morning...

Answer (score 4):

If you look above the error, XCode will tell you which class is added/declared twice, navigate to it and remove the reference. Build and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

A suggestion is to update the pods to the latest. I recently stucked into a similar type of problem. so I did this and it worked for me. my pod version was older.

check it with pod --version, may be this helps you.

```
pod deintegrate
pod install
pod update
```

Answer (score 0):

I do everything restarts Xcode, rebuild Project, adding toolChains, lock unlock them, but nothing works for me
so there are two possibilities
first, maybe you install the beta version of Xcode

or try this, this work for me->

I tried to run a project in Xcode12/Swift4, while the project was written on Xcode8/Swift3
so I install  Xcode version 11.7 and run this work for me.

if you not done with 11.7 then install another version of Xcode and try the appreciated version
May this help you