# Xcode archive failed with error exit code 1

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

when I'm trying to publish my *React native* application, I first try to build an app and it builds successfully. Then when product » archive I get the following error:

> ld: 513 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64 clang:
>      error: linker command failed with exit code 1
>     *(use -v to see invocation)*

note: I'm using the *.xcworkspace* file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 10.0 Error "Command /Applications/Xcode 10.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53001665/xcode-10-0-error-command-applications-xcode-10-app-contents-developer-toolchai)

Answer (score -1):

You probably have React Native included in your project file, and also installed a CocoaPod which includes React Native as a dependency, so you have 2 copies of React Native. Delete one.

Comment: Build system already identifies that there Podfile and then installs it